# Android Java MediaStore sort order case sensitivity

Tags: java, android, audio, media, mediastore

For MediaStore, I'm able to sort the display name alphabetically. But this doesn't take into consideration case sensitivity. When I run the code below, it puts capitals at the top of the list and lowercases at the bottom.

How do I ignore the case sensitivity?

```
String[] proj = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID, 
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, 
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, 
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST};

    String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC";

    musiccursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, 
                  proj, selection, null, sortOrder);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try lower(sortOrder)

Answer (score 4):

String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE NOCASE ASC";